# Copy input file text to new span & trim the value.

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input

I've styled a file input (making the opacity=0) but I would like to display the slected file in a new span. I've copied the input value and pasted it into a span with jquery:

```
        $('#file').on('change', function () {
            $('#filemask').val($(this).val());
        }).change();
```

So, I'm getting this value: "**C:\fakepath\file.txt**". I'm not sure how to trim the first 12 characters from the value so that I'm just left with: "**file.txt**"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#file').on('change', function () {
   var parts = $(this).val().split('\\');
   $('#filemask').val(parts[parts.length -1]);
}).change();
```